# U-boot static IP doesn't seem to "apply"

Tags: networking, u-boot

When I enter the command `setenv ippaddr xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx` it doesn't seem to actually connect to the network on that address.

I have a private network set up with the address in the same subnet but communication between the two never succeed.

Comment: Did you follow all the steps outlined here? http://www.dilnetpc.com/mHTA9200-05.pdf

Comment: Does Uboot have to be reset after setting the static ip? I don't have flash to save the configs too....

Comment: I know nothing about this other than what I provided you from the docs. I've never used this h/w before.

Answer (score 1):

According to this document you have to do the following:

```
U-Boot> setenv ipaddr 192.168.1.126
U-Boot> setenv serverip 192.168.1.1
U-Boot> setenv netmask 255.255.255.0
U-Boot> saveenv
Saving Environment to Flash...
Un-Protected 1 sectors
Erasing Flash...
. done
Erased 1 sectors
Writing to Flash... done
Protected 1 sectors
U-Boot>
```

#### References

- [How to change the U-Boot IP Addresses for the LAN1 Ethernet Interface](http://www.dilnetpc.com/mHTA9200-05.pdf)

Comment: I cannot save configs